# Why no index out of range error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = [
8,2,22,97,38,15,0,40,0,75,4,5,7,78,52,12,50,77,91,8,             #0-19
49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,4,56,62,0,       #20-39
81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,3,49,13,36,65,      #40-59
52,70,95,23,4,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,1,32,56,71,37,2,36,91,
22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80,
24,47,32,60,99,3,45,2,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50,
32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70,
67,26,20,68,2,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,8,40,91,66,49,94,21,
24,55,58,5,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72,
21,36,23,9,75,0,76,44,20,45,35,14,0,61,33,97,34,31,33,95,
78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,3,80,4,62,16,14,9,53,56,92,
16,39,5,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,0,17,54,24,36,29,85,57,
86,56,0,48,35,71,89,7,5,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58,
19,80,81,68,5,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,4,89,55,40,
4,52,8,83,97,35,99,16,7,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66,
88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,3,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69,
4,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,8,46,29,32,40,62,76,36,     #320-339
20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,4,36,16,    #340-359
20,73,35,29,78,31,90,1,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,5,54,     #360-379
1,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,1,89,19,67,48]     #380-399

prodsum = 1

def prod(iter):
   p = 1
    for n in iter:
         p *= n
     return p

for n in range(0,5000,20):    #NOT OUT OF RANGE???
    for i in range(0,17):
        if prod(lst[n+i:n+i+4]) > prodsum:
            prodsum = prod(lst[n+i:n+i+4])
```

I'm trying to learn/improve my very rudimentary skills in Python so I've been going through Project Euler challenges. The challenge question is more complex but I basically have a 20x20 grid and have the find 4 adjacent numbers with the largest product.

I basically turned the grid into a list (with 400 values) and was gonna scan row indices. I accidentally entered in a large number for my for loop and noticed I didn't get a out of range error. Why is this?

Comment: Be careful using the name of a built-in function `iter` as a name in Python since it will destroy that function's name in that scope.

Comment: Slices don't raise those exceptions: `assert [][1000:10000] == []`.

Comment: @dawg thank you, didn't think about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *would get* an out-of-range error with plain indexing. Eg, if you had an array of 10 elements, and you asked for `my_list[20]`. However, with *slicing* `my_array[a: b]` you either get elements from `a` to `b-1`, or to the end of the list. That's just a design decision of the language.

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a out-of-range as you never directly access your list based on your index (`n`).

You use `lst[n+i:n+i+4]` to get a slice of `lst` ... which just is empty if your indices are out of range so `prod(...)` is called with `[]` and returns `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing outside the bounds of a sequence doesn't cause an error. If you try to index **single item**, you'll got an error.